# Take a snapshot of current screen with Metal in swift

Tags: swift, metal

I tried:

```
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale        
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(metalLayer.bounds.size, false, scale)
            
// metalLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

// self.view.layer ...

metalLayer.presentationLayer()!.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()           
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

But the result is an empty screenshot. Any help would be nice!

*Please keep in mind that I want to take a snapshot of a `CAMetalLayer`.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***To make a screenshot, you need to get `MTLTexture` of the frame buffer.***

**1. If you use `MTKView`:**

```
let texture = view.currentDrawable!.texture
```

**2. If you don't use `MTKView`**

Here's what I would do - I would have a property which holds last drawable presented to the screen:

```
let lastDrawableDisplayed: CAMetalDrawable?
```

And then when you present drawable to the screen, I would update it:

```
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { buffer in
  self.lastDrawableDisplayed = drawable
}
```

Now you whenever you need to take a screenshot, you can get a texture like this:

```
let texture = lastDrawableDisplayed.texture
```

Ok, now when you have `MTLTexture` you can convert it to `CGImage` and then to `UIImage` or `NSImage`.

Here's the code for OS X playground *(MetalKit.MTLTextureLoader is not available for iOS playgrounds)*, in which I convert `MTLTexture` to `CGImage`

I made a small extension over `MTLTexture` for this.

```
import Metal
import MetalKit
import Cocoa

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)

let path = "path/to/your/image.jpg"
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!

let texture = try! textureLoader.newTextureWithData(data, options: nil)

extension MTLTexture {
  
  func bytes() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> {
    let width = self.width
    let height = self.height
    let rowBytes = self.width * 4
    let p = malloc(width * height * 4)
    
    self.getBytes(p, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, fromRegion: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)
    
    return p
  }
  
  func toImage() -> CGImage? {
    let p = bytes()
    
    let pColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    
    let rawBitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: rawBitmapInfo)
    
    let selftureSize = self.width * self.height * 4
    let rowBytes = self.width * 4
    let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, p, selftureSize, nil)
    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreate(self.width, self.height, 8, 32, rowBytes, pColorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)!
    
    return cgImageRef
  }
}

if let imageRef = texture.toImage() {
  let image = NSImage(CGImage: imageRef, size: NSSize(width: texture.width, height: texture.height))
}
```

Comment: at least one `}` is missing.

Comment: Doesn't capture transparent background.

Answer (score 10):

For swift 4.0,
Just converting code provided by haawa

```
let lastDrawableDisplayed = metalView?.currentDrawable?.texture

if let imageRef = lastDrawableDisplayed?.toImage() {
    let uiImage:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: imageRef)
}

extension MTLTexture {

    func bytes() -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        let width = self.width
        let height   = self.height
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        let p = malloc(width * height * 4)

        self.getBytes(p!, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)

        return p!
    }

    func toImage() -> CGImage? {
        let p = bytes()

        let pColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        let rawBitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: rawBitmapInfo)

        let selftureSize = self.width * self.height * 4
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
            return
        }
        let provider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: p, size: selftureSize, releaseData: releaseMaskImagePixelData)
        let cgImageRef = CGImage(width: self.width, height: self.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, space: pColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!

        return cgImageRef
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much because in my case it is unique way to get image https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage3#capturing-and-filtering-a-still-photo #GPUImage3

Comment: Doesn't work for me: _validateGetBytes:51: failed assertion `texture must not be a framebufferOnly texture.'

Answer (score 5):

I didn't manage to get the accepted answer to work in Swift 4 / Metal 2 with XCode 9.1 on an iPhone 6s. Therefore I used a slightly different approach assuming `lastDrawableDisplayed` is saved as described in the accepted answer. Quick and dirty and without any exception handling:

```
let context = CIContext()
let texture = self.lastDrawableDisplayed!.texture
let cImg = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: nil)!
let cgImg = context.createCGImage(cImg, from: cImg.extent)!
let uiImg = UIImage(cgImage: cgImg)
```

This is based on the documentation on the used [CIImage Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437890-init):

> `init(mtlTexture:options:)` Initializes an image object with data supplied by a Metal texture.

and [CIImage Processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-TPXREF101) which describes how to create a `CGImage` with the use of `CIContext`:

> `CIContext()` Create[s] a CIContext object (with default options) [...] `context.createCGImage` Render[s] the output image to a Core Graphics image that you can display or save to a file.

Hope that helps for anyone using Swift 4.

Edit: Additionally, I have multiple overlaying `CAMetalLayer` in my project and want to combine them into one single `UIImage`. Therefore it is needed to have references to the last `CAMetalDrawable` object of each layer. Before a new layer is added (and therefore used as the provider of `nextDrawable()`) I simply add the `lastDrawableDisplayed` to an array `[CAMetalDrawable]`. When "exporting" the layers I simply write all UIImages subsequently into a bitmap-based graphics context and get the final image with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`.

Edit: If you are having trouble with orientation, try the following:

```
let uiImg = UIImage(cgImage: cgImg, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.downMirrored)
```

Comment: Approach with `CIImage` works for me when I need to capture snapshot with transparent background! Thank you!

Comment: this is a brilliant answer!

Comment: Does not work for me either: `-[MTLDebugComputeCommandEncoder setTexture:atIndex:]:373: failed assertion frameBufferOnly texture not supported for compute.`

Needed (with performance hit): `metalView.framebufferOnly = false`

Answer (score 0):

MTLTexture's method toImage needs to release data's memory in release data callback:

```
let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
            data.dealloc()
            return
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory leak issue due to not free bytes created for CGDataProvider.
From @Ankit Kedia answer.

Here is a Swift 5.0 version complete code.

```
extension MTLTexture {
    func bytes() -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        let width = self.width
        let height = self.height
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        let p = malloc(width * height * 4)!
        getBytes(p, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)
        return p
    }

    func toImage() -> CGImage? {
        let p = self.bytes()
        let pColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let rawBitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: rawBitmapInfo)
        
        let selftureSize = self.width * self.height * 4
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        if let provider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: p, size: selftureSize, releaseData: { _, p, _ in
            p.deallocate()
        }) {
            return CGImage(width: width,
                           height: height,
                           bitsPerComponent: 8,
                           bitsPerPixel: 32,
                           bytesPerRow: rowBytes,
                           space: pColorSpace,
                           bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
                           provider: provider,
                           decode: nil,
                           shouldInterpolate: true,
                           intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

swift 4.2

```
extension MTLTexture {
    
    func bytes() -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
        let width = self.width
        let height   = self.height
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        let p = malloc(width * height * 4)
        
        self.getBytes(p!, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, from: MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height), mipmapLevel: 0)
        
        return p!
    }
    
    func toImage() -> CGImage? {
        let p = bytes()
        
        let pColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        
        let rawBitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
        let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: rawBitmapInfo)
        
        let selftureSize = self.width * self.height * 4
        let rowBytes = self.width * 4
        let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
            return
        }
        let provider = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: p, size: selftureSize, releaseData: releaseMaskImagePixelData)
        let cgImageRef = CGImage(width: self.width, height: self.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bitsPerPixel: 32, bytesPerRow: rowBytes, space: pColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, provider: provider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)!
        
        return cgImageRef
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of @Ankit's answer