# How to get a snapshot of current drawable with metal on mac?

Tags: metal

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844130/take-a-snapshot-of-current-screen-with-metal-in-swift) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115605/how-can-i-make-screen-shot-image-from-mtkview-in-ios). 
I tried the following codes, it works fine in `iOS 12.1.4` but empty on `macOS Mojave version 10.14`

```
    id<CAMetalDrawable> lastDrawable = view.currentDrawable;
    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer) {
        id<MTLTexture> drawableTexture = lastDrawable.texture;
        int width = (int)drawableTexture.width;
        int height = (int)drawableTexture.height;
        int len = width * height * 4;
        uint8_t* image = (uint8_t*)malloc(len);
        [drawableTexture getBytes:image bytesPerRow:width*4 fromRegion:MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height) mipmapLevel:0];

        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                           image,
                                                           width,
                                                           height,
                                                           8, // bitsPerComponent
                                                           4*width, // bytesPerRow
                                                           colorSpace,
                                                           kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);

        CFRelease(colorSpace);

        CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
        CFRelease(cgImage);
        CFRelease(bitmapContext);
        free(image);
    }];
```

Do I need some additional processes to get a correct snapshot of the current screen on mac?

Comment: Did you set the `framebufferOnly` property on your view to false? Anyway, I dislike everybody's tendency to copy from the drawable's texture. If you want to keep the drawn frame, draw it to a texture of your own and then blit that to the drawable.

Comment: Yes, I set the view. framebufferOnly to NO or otherwise it will validate fail.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder what the storage mode is for a drawable's texture. If it's managed, then you need to use a blit command encoder to encode a `-synchronize...` command. Otherwise, the data isn't guaranteed to be available to the CPU.

Comment: You are right, the storage mode for a drawable's texture is `MTLStorageModeManaged`, and need a `-synchronize...` by an `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`. It works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage mode of the drawable's texture is managed. You need to use a blit command encoder to encode a `-synchronize...` command. Otherwise, the data isn't guaranteed to be available to the CPU.