# Copy Metal frame buffer texture for reading

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a MetalKit view (MTKView) like in the answer [Take a snapshot of current screen with Metal in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844130/take-a-snapshot-of-current-screen-with-metal-in-swift) but it requires that the MTKView set framebufferOnly to false which disables some optimizations according to Apple.

Is there a way to copy the MTKView texture (e.g. view.currentDrawable.texture) so that I can read the pixels? I don't need to take screenshots often so it would be a shame to disable the optimization for the entire lifecycle of the program running.

I tried using MTLTexture.newTextureViewWithPixelFormat and blit buffers but I still get the same exception about the frame buffer only being true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a screenshot is requested, you could toggle `framebufferOnly`, do one rendering pass, and then toggle it back.

Alternatively, you can do one rendering pass targeting a texture of your own specification, blit that to the drawable's texture (so as not to visually drop a frame), and then save the contents of your own texture.

Comment: I didn't even think about rendering to another target (like FBO's in OpenGL I think) but that's probably the best approach. Is that done by setting the texture in the color attachment of MTLRenderPassDescriptor?

Comment: and also do you know how to force a render pass using MetalKit? I tried toggling framebufferOnly first but I seems to require a allow some number of event loops to pass before it registers. Honestly it's not even clear when to take the screen shot in the render loop so maybe I'm messing that up also.

Comment: Yes, you just set the color attachment texture in the render pass descriptor. Also, the color attachment pixel format in the render pipeline descriptor has to match. You can invoke `draw` on your `MTKView` to force a render pass. By the way, you must not access the texture contents until after the command buffer has completed and be sure to have a blit command encoder put a `synchronize` command in there at the end, too.

Comment: I decided to go with toggling frameBufferOnly. Strangely it requires calling MTKView.draw 3x after setting  frameBufferOnly to false or I get a blank image.