# Saving and Loading MTLTexture as PNG

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to save and load Metal textures as PNGs, but when I load them back they appear blurrier. I think the problem is that converting a texture that's 800x600 creates a PNG that's 1600x1200, so I have to downscale the PNG to load it into an MTLTexture of the correct size.

Here's my code for converting a texture to PNG data:

```swift
  func textureToImage(texture: MTLTexture) -> Data {
    let kciOptions: [CIImageOption:Any] = [.colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()]
    let ciImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: kciOptions)!
    let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                      .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)
                      .translatedBy(x: 0, y: ciImage.extent.height)
    let transformed = ciImage.transformed(by: transform)
    return UIImage(ciImage: transformed).pngData()!
  }
```

For an example of the 2x scaling problem:

```swift
  let texture: MTLTexture = ...
  texture.width // => 800
  let image = textureToImage(texture)
  image.size.width // => 800
  let data = image.pngData()!
  let reloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)!
  reloadedImage.size.width // => 1600
```

So CIImage seems to double the resolution when converting the texture to an image. Here's my code for converting it back, where I think the downscaling is causing blurriness:

```swift
  func load(_ image: UIImage) -> MTLTexture {
    // The image is twice the texture resolution so we have to scale it down
    let scaled = scale(image: image, scale: 0.5)

    let options: [MTKTextureLoader.Option: Any] = [
      .SRGB: false,
      .generateMipmaps: true,
      .textureUsage: MTLTextureUsage.unknown.rawValue
    ]

    let loader = MTKTextureLoader(device: Renderer.device)
    let texture = try! loader.newTexture(cgImage: scaled, options: options)
    return texture.makeTextureView(pixelFormat: .bgra8Unorm)!
  }

  func scale(image: UIImage, scale: Float) -> CGImage {
    let scale = CGFloat(scale)
    let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!.cgImage!
  }
```

Is there a way for me to load the UIImage back into an MTLTexture without having to scale it down? Or alternatively, is there a way to avoid CIImage doubling the resolution of the texture when it's converted to an image? I need to store my textures as PNGs because I have a lot of them and they eat up too much memory as raw texture data.

Answer (score 1):

```objectivec
- (void)textureToImage:(id<MTLTexture>)texture {
    CIContext *context = [[CIContext alloc] initWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithMTLTexture:texture options:nil];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, ciImage.extent.size.height);
    ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
    NSLog(@"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this issue when saving `MTLTexture` to PNG via `CIImage` using `UIImage.pngData`. My PNG file dimensions were being multiplied by the screen-scale despite the intermediate `UIImage.scale` value being 1.

In my case I resolved the issue by simply removing `CIImage` from the loop. I now create a `CGImage` directly from `MTLTexture` (using a technique similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50618976/58271)) then create the `UIImage` from that `CGImage` and call `UIImage.pngData`.

I suspect there is some kind of `UIImage` metadata beyond just `scale` property which `CIImage(mtlTexture:options:)` or `UIImage(ciImage:scale:orientation:)` isn't setting correctly.