# Take screenshot of the screen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a hierarchy of a mix of `UIView`s, `MTKView`s, and SwiftUI's `View`s. The most outer view is a `ZStack` that stack them together. Just as a arbitrary example:

```
ZStack
  `-SwiftUI View
    `-SwiftUI View
      `-SwiftUI View
    `-UIViewRepresentable (MTKView)
  `-UIView
  `-SwiftUI View
  `-UIViewRepresentable (MTKView)
```

I tried to take a screenshot of this view with these and none worked: `ImageRenderer` (return nil), putting it in a `UIHostingViewController` and take the screenshot the old way of `UIKit` (`MKTView`s are not rendered), using `snapshotView()` on the `UIHostingViewController`'s view and take the screenshot of that (empty image). I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844130/take-a-snapshot-of-current-screen-with-metal-in-swift) to take a screenshot of MTKView, but for this, I'll have to take a screenshot of each view in the hierarchy and stack them recursively manually. That's not ideal.

Do we have any other way to take a screenshot of a view or simply the device's screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This returns screenshot of the specified view (it can be top container also with all included subviews, WYSIWYG)

```
extension UIView {

func snapshot() -> UIImage? {
    if self.bounds == .zero {
        return nil
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it doesn't take the MTKViews

Comment: I found this solution for MTKView. Maybe this will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844130/take-a-snapshot-of-current-screen-with-metal-in-swift/33903182#33903182

Comment: Thanks @Dzmitry Sotnikov, I found that too, but that requires me to merge the stack manually which is quite tedious, I also have opacity and blend modes as well. So it will be prone to error and not performant as sometimes it could be up to 100 MTKViews or more